# Python match all substrings and reversed strings

Tags: python, file-io, substring, matching

I have to match all occurrences of substring in a string and return all match starting positions:

example of input data:

```
2 4 
AC
TGGT 
4 25 
CATA 
TCATATGCAAATAGCTGCATACCGA 
0 0  ## to end the file
```

I would like to do this without using numbers in such lines as it seems not really necessary;(but they will still be in the input files)

And I don't know exactly what's wrong with this code, but it keeps printing (infinity  loop) of printing 0s on the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from operator import itemgetter
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testnum=0
    input_file =  open(sys.argv[1])
    #input_lines=input_file.split("\n")
    output_file =  open(sys.argv[2],"w")
    while True:
       testnum+=1
       values_raw = input_file.readline()
       #values_raw=raw_input() ##rubish
       values=values_raw.split()
       flag=0
       for element in values:
           if element == "0":
          break
       string1=str(input_file.readline())
       string2=str(input_file.readline())
       lista = find_all(string2,string1)
       output_file.write("\nTeste "+str(testnum)+"\nocorrencia direta: ")
       for item in lista:
         output_file.write(str(item)+" ") 
       #reversed search
       string1=string1[::-1]
       lista = find_all(string2,string1)
       output_file.write("\nTeste "+str(testnum)+"\nocorrencia inversa complementar: ")
       for item in lista:
         output_file.write(str(item)+" ") 
       if ((len(string1)==0)):
         break
```

I accidentally removed the string1 and string2 lines when pasting the code //I match for the original and for the reversed match, but as the code is almost the same I thought I shouldn't  post it too.

Comment: `if element == 0` is always false. `element` is a `str`, not a number. besides, `string1` and `string2` are never assigned into - they have no binding in this code.

Comment: I accidentally removed them in the original posting, but I believe that what I did to read the files is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = 'CATA'
>>> strs = 'TCATATGCAAATAGCTGCATACCGA'
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(pat, strs)]
[1, 17]
```

Comment: If he wants to match the reverse pattern he can just do `set([m.start() for m in re.finditer(pat, strs)]) & set([m.start() for m in re.finditer(pat[::-1], strs)])`